# Cannot read property 'state' of undefined react hooks

Tags: reactjs

Hello everyone this is my first attempt to use react hooks , im building a multi step antd from using react hooks so i can pass all the values to the last step and submit it to firebase. However im getting an issue saying Cannot read property 'state' of undefined when trying to get the state of current step. I have no idea what im doing wrong so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { Menu, Icon, Button, Popover, Badge } from "antd";
import Header from "./Header";
import First from "./First";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { useForm, useStep } from "react-hooks-helper";
import firebase from "./Firebase";
import {
  Form,
  Input,
  Tooltip,
  Cascader,
  Tag,
  Select,
  Row,
  Col,
  Option,
  InputNumber,
  Checkbox,
  AutoComplete,
} from "antd";
import Second from "./Second";
import Third from "./Third";
import { QuestionCircleOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

import { Steps, message } from "antd";

const Step = Steps.Step;
const defaultData = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "Doe",
  address: "",
  city: "",
  state: "CA",
  zip: "",
  lat: "",
  long: "",
  email: "",
  phone: "",
  supply: [],
};

const steps = [
  {
    title: "",
    content: <First />,
  },
  {
    title: "",
    content: <Second />,
  },
  {
    title: "",
    content: <Third />,
  },
];

const Help = ({ images }) => {
  const AutoCompleteOption = AutoComplete.Option;
  const [formData, setForm] = useForm(defaultData);
  const { step, navigation } = useStep({ initialStep: 0, steps });
  const { id } = step;

  const props = { formData, setForm, navigation };

  const [current, setCount] = useState(0);

  console.log(current);
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <br />
      <Steps current={current}>
        {steps.map((item) => (
          <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
        ))}
      </Steps>
      <div className="steps-content">{steps[current].content}</div>
      <div className="steps-action">
        //this is where i get error {current < steps.length - 1 && (
          <Button type="primary" onClick={() => setCount(current + 1)}>
            Next
          </Button>
        )}
        {current === steps.length - 1 && (
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => message.success("Processing complete!")}
          >
            Done
          </Button>
        )}
        {this.state.current > 0 && (
          <Button
            style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}
            onClick={() => setCount(current - 1)}
          >
            Previous
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Help;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.state.current`, which is the way to access state within a class component. Here you have direct access to your state with `current`.